# How to use org headers as filenames in tangle

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, literate-programming, tangle

In org mode, how can I tangle to files equally named as the org header?

Referring to the examples below, I'd expect two files `foo.sh` and `bar.sh` as tangle result:

```
* foo
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle yes
ls
#+END_SRC

* bar
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle yes
ls
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I presume you want it to automatically get the heading, but setting `:tangle foo.sh` instead of `:tangle yes` will certainly work as a workaround. It's a little more work but not bad at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Define a new function in `elisp` using [Org Element API](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) to that returns `:title` property of headline element.

For this answer, I wrote a `headline-title` function that returns the `:title` of the nearest headline above the `SRC` block.

```
(defun headline-title() 
  (let* ((x 
      (save-mark-and-excursion 
       (org-up-heading-safe) 
        (org-element-property :title (org-element-at-point)))))
    (if (and x (not (string-match file-name-invalid-regexp x))) (format "%s" x) "yes" ))
  )
```

> **Note:** The new function that you will define will need to be added to Library of Babel, your local configuration files, or as a file variable inside your org-mode file.

In this example, I've added the `headline-title` function as a file variable to the org-mode file.

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (defun headline-title nil (let* ((x (save-mark-and-excursion (org-up-heading-safe) (org-element-property :title (org-element-at-point))))) (if (and x (not (string-match file-name-invalid-regexp x))) (format "%s" x) "yes")))
# End:
```

> **Tip:** After adding the `headline-title` function as file variable, save file, close file and re-open your file in emacs. Each time you open the file, you will be prompted to enable the new file variable.

---

#### Call new function, e.g. `headline-title`, with the `:tangle` header

For this example, I defined a single `:tangle` header for all the `SRC` blocks under each headline.

```
* bar
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :tangle (headline-title)
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  echo "bar"
#+END_SRC

* foo
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :tangle (headline-title)
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  echo "foo"
#+END_SRC
```

---

#### For `SRC` blocks defined outside of headlines, the code example returns `yes` to the `:tangle` header.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :tangle (headline-title)
  echo "No Headline"
#+END_SRC
```

---

#### Headlines with Formatting or Punctuation might be Bad Choice for File Name when  Tangling

```
* Bad FileName?
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :tangle (headline-title)
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  echo "Headline might be Bad File Name"
#+END_SRC

* /etc/passwd-OMG-C-g-C-g-C-x-C-c-I-just-broke-my-unix-server-using-org-mode
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sh: :tangle (headline-title)
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  echo "Headlines with Formatting might be Bad Choice for File Name when Tangling"
#+END_SRC
```

---

### **Thanks for asking your question!**

> **This answer was tested using:**
>   **emacs:** GNU Emacs 25.2.1
>   **org-mode:** Org mode version 9.1.2